# Can't fit a Gamma distribution using glmer

Tags: r, model, lme4

I am trying to fit a Gamma distribution (I ran the model with lmer but the residuals are not normally distributed) in a GLMM.

My response variable is a list of numeric values (biomass), my fixed effects are two factors (with 2 levels each) and a date, my random effects are all factors.

Here is the model:

```
mod1 <- glmer(biomass~treatment+date+canopy+(1|block)+(1|site/sUbsite),
              family=Gamma, data=biomass_evol)
```

But I run into an error:

> Error in length(value <- as.numeric(value)) == 1L : 
>     (maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate

I don't understand what this error mean.

Comment: you could try the log link rather than inverse ... `Gamma(link="log")`

Comment: It works! Thanks! However, I look at the summary of the model, I find that it considers each date as a different fixed effect... even though it is a factor with 8 levels... can you explain this, and how to fix the problem..?

Comment: you're welcome. It's hard to say ... if your date has 8 levels you would expect to see 7 fixed effects (+1 in the intercept). Can you edit your question to add the results from `str(biomass_evol)` please. s I'd also have a wee think if using date as a factor is sensible.